# How can a website detect automated extraction?

Tags: java, url, iostream

I was working on a simple application to pull some currency conversions from a website, when I received an error message (below) stating they had a no automated extraction policy.

**Autoextraction Prohibited**

**Automated extraction of our content is prohibited.  See http://www.xe.com/errors/noautoextract.htm.**

I don't really have an intention of breaking their policy but I am curious as to how they can tell. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) User-Agent

2) Introducing a Javascript pop-up.Something like `Click OK to enter`.

3) Calculating number of request/hour from a particular ip address if you are not behind NAT.

For more detail take a look at this Pycon talk [web-strategies-for-programming-websites-that-don-t-expected-it](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-scrape-the-web-strategies-for-programming-websites-that-don-t-expected-it-3378693) by **asheesh laroia**.

Also take a look at [A Standard for Robot Exclusion](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

Some web-sites also use

4) Captchas and Re-Captchas

5) Redirection which means you need to add a `HTTP Referrer` to get your data.

Answer (score 1):

It is done at the HTTP Server level by implementing [Robot Exclusion protocol](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

From [Robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

> The Robot Exclusion Standard, also known as the Robots Exclusion
>   Protocol or robots.txt protocol, is a convention to prevent
>   cooperating web crawlers and other web robots from accessing all or
>   part of a website which is otherwise publicly viewable. Robots are
>   often used by search engines to categorize and archive web sites, or
>   by webmasters to proofread source code.

Comment: This doesn't stop bad robots that simply choose to ignore the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I think they watch at least two parameters :

- the number of queries from the same IP in a time interval
- User-Agent header in your HTTP queries. If it's empty or it doesn't look like a web browser's User-Agent header, especially if it indicates "Java" or something like that ;), they can assume it's not a "fair use".

Comment: Hmmm, I was figuring they would count queries, but I only did the one. I'm not familiar with User-Agents, though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you request an URL and you get the HTML page back, there's pretty much nothing the site can do about it - and well, that's just what a webserver is for.

But there are several [techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Technical_measures_to_stop_bots) to stop bots in contrast of a human being requesting the page. Some of them are hints for bots which "behave", others try to detect a bot and stop it.